# Measure volume of data downloaded and uploaded

Tags: vb6, bandwidth

I need to calculate Downloaded and uploaded data using vb6. Monitor Internet usage in terms of download+upload  and restrict the user

Comment: You must provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to write a PeerGuardian type program? This is quite difficult, but yry looking at things like this, a SOCKS5 application in VB6...

http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5057